# How to make an activity indecator with a WKwebView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4

I am trying to make an iOS app with Swift and I have sorted out the webView which works perfectly, however now i'd like to implement an activity indicator. It displays properly and is animated, however when the page is loaded, the activity indicator does not disappear.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var webview: WKWebView!
 //   @IBOutlet var bg: UIView!
   // @IBOutlet var logo: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet var ActInd: UIActivityIndicatorView!

   // @IBOutlet var LoadingLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webview.load(request)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

 func webViewDidStartLoad(_ : WKWebView) {
        ActInd.startAnimating()
        //LoadingLabel.isHidden = true
        //logo.isHidden = true
        //bg.isHidden = true

    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ : WKWebView){
        ActInd.stopAnimating()
       // LoadingLabel.isHidden = true
        //logo.isHidden = true
        //bg.isHidden=true
    }


}
```

I'd appreciate it enormously if someone could help me get the activity indicator to disappear.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conform to WKNavigationDelegate, and you can track webView processes..

> The methods of the WKNavigationDelegate protocol help you implement custom behaviors that are triggered during a web view's process of accepting, loading, and completing a navigation request.

There are two methods that you can use :

`func webView(WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation: WKNavigation!)`

Called when web content begins to load in a web view.

Here you can show the activity indicator

`func webView(WKWebView, didFinish: WKNavigation!)`

Called when the navigation is complete.

For more info check [WKNavigationDelegate documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate)

So here are the steps :

1- Conform to WKNavigationDelegate.

2- Assign your view controller to be your web view’s navigationDelegate.

3- Implement `didStartProvisionalNavigation` and `didFinish` methods

Example :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var webview: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webview.navigationDelegate = self
        /*
         ....
         */
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        // hide/stop indicator
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        //show your activity
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

```
ActInd.hidesWhenStopped = true // In viewDidLoad
```

Comment: I have tried it and I don't get an error but it also does not do anything

Comment: what're you trying to achieve ? the answer was mentioned for the question above

Answer (score 0):

On view did load just start your indicator and on webViewDidFinishLoad just hide that loader.

Comment: I did that like this :  `func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ : WKWebView){
        ActInd.isHidden = true
       // LoadingLabel.isHidden = true
        //logo.isHidden = true
        //bg.isHidden=true
    }` and it doesn't do anything

Comment: You just add in into main dispatch method.

Answer (score 0):

The methods won't ever be called.

Because, you haven't set your ViewController as NavigationDelegate. It needs to conform to the [WKNavigationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate). You can then set the delegate in the viewDidLoad() function:

```
webview.navigationDelegate = self
```

The 2 methods you're calling also don't seem to exist. These are the equivalent delegate methods: [webView(*:didCommit:)*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455635-webview) and [webView(:didFinish:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455629-webview)

You can set "Hides when stopped" and "Animated" in the storyboard or do it programatically as it is explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46463707/8126260).

You should also take a look at the [API Design guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/) explaining how code should be written. Especially you should:

> Follow case conventions. Names of types and protocols are UpperCamelCase. Everything else is lowerCamelCase.